# On how double precision numbers are encoded in a pdf file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdf, file-size

Imagine the following tikz/pgfplots code:

```
% compile as: lualatex --jobname=figname-f1 figname.tex
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\pgfrealjobname{figname}
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=6 
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\begin{document}
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{figname-f1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=6cm,scale only axis,axis lines=left,axis]
\addplot3 coordinates{
(8.27605704077856,0.505526531790625,1.15577754382534e-05)
(8.27605704077856,1.01105306358125,4.16291426502054e-06)
(8.27605704077856,1.51657959537188,3.77146738938349e-06)
.... % many more lines similar to the one above
};
```

This tex file is about 3Mb. Compile it to get `figname-f1.pdf`. Now replace by zero all the third components that are very small, ie:

```
\addplot3 coordinates{
(8.27605704077856,0.505526531790625,0)
(8.27605704077856,1.01105306358125,0)
(8.27605704077856,1.51657959537188,0)
.... % many more lines similar to the one above
};
```

This new tex file is about 2Mb. Compile it.

In the personal examples I am working on, the two .pdf files are of the same size, about 530kb. Is that expected?

Comment: What's "1Mo"? [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1Mo) suggests 1 month, but I don't think the difference would be that big.

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected, since these are just coordinates, and there is virtually no difference in the placement of the markers in those locations. The difference in the `.tex` file stems from the loss in characters.

Comment: What is `1Mo`?  Keep in mind that file sizes on computers are not continuous, they are usually in 4k chunks to optimize disk performance.  So, if you are seeing size differences in the .tex (whcih are just plain text files) with such small changes then it is probably because you crossed this quantized amount.

Comment: @Werner: ha yes I see, it is because points are then projected on the plane. Too bad.

Comment: @doncherry: Sorry, I meant MegaBytes.

Comment: @doncherry The French prefer to call them "mégaoctets" rather than "mebibytes" (or "megabytes") and I find this perfectly legitimate. It's futile, though, using a symbol which is not understood outside of France (this is not a rebuke to pluton, of course). By the way, the IEC proposed the symbol MiB, which is endorsed by IEEE and CIPM ([source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte))

Comment: @Werner Can you make your comment an answer? Seems like that's the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to note that (La)TeX *interprets* the code and generates output. Output in this instance is the resulting PDF which, in its binary form, consists of a bunch of shapes (circles, lines, rectangles and some embedded content like fonts, perhaps).

It may be that the interpretation of (2,3) results in a generalized representation of (2.0000000,3.0000000) in PDF binary form, thereby *inflating* the size of the resulting PDF to accommodate for accuracy up to 7 decimals<sup>*</sup>. However, this also means that specifying accuracy beyond 7 decimals may be rounded/truncated (or *deflated*). This standardization on the output side of things results in similar-sized PDFs even though the input may very dramatically in terms of its precision under the condition that you keep the number & type of objects/shapes the same.

Whether you place an object/shape in your code (input) at position (2,3), position (2.0,3.0), position (2.0001,3.0001) or at position (2.718281828459045,3.141592653589793), the result (output) will still be the same object/shape in two dimensions in the PDF. So, the same size output is expected.

<sup><sup>*</sup> I'm not sure about the accuracy used in PDF binaries. This was just an example.</sup>